# OpenCv in Clion

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc, cygwin

Hi I am getting this error I have installed OpenCV libraries in Cygwin [Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrpEb.png)

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/imageprocessing.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `cv::String::~String()':
/usr/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:648: undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/imageprocessing.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `cv::String::operator=(cv::String const&)':
/usr/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:656: undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/imageprocessing.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
/usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:704: undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/imageprocessing.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `cv::Mat::release()':
/usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:816: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/imageprocessing.dir/build.make:93: imageprocessing.exe] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/imageprocessing.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:90: CMakeFiles/imageprocessing.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:124: imageprocessing] Error 2**
```

CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(imageprocessing)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

add_executable(imageprocessing main.cpp)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
```

**User Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Mat image;
    cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you read the manual https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html? The hint: further actions are required after `find_package`.

Comment: Usually you will put `find_package()` near the top. It's not required though. It should be before a `target_link_libraries()` which your CMakeLists.txt misses.

Comment: i have added the libraries in Cygwin installation **Check Image [Libraries][1]**